# Elasticsearch sort by dates is incorrect

Tags: elasticsearch

In the Elasticsearch documents, there is a field createdAt defined as follows:

```
"createdAt" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
          }
```

When trying to sort the records by date, I get the following order:

1. 2019-10-01 07:46:22
2. 2019-10-01 09:06:28
3. 2019-10-01 10:39:43
4. 2019-10-01 11:35:00
5. 2019-10-02 12:27:40
6. 2019-10-04 00:50:00
7. 2019-07-05 09:57:15
8. 2019-11-05 22:58:00
9. 2019-06-06 12:39:49
10. 2019-09-06 19:46:00

Does anyone know why the dates are not sorted correctly?

Comment: What is your query to sort by date ?

Comment: it seems to me that it's applying the format YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: Please update your question with the query you are using to get the results.

Comment: Is it possible that you changed the date format after having indexed a couple documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format is wrong, it should be:

```
"createdAt" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
```

Lowercase `y` and `d`