# Getting timstamp from date field in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field validTo defined as date:

```
"validTo" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
          }
```

an example entry value is "2019-12-02 14:32:43"

If I try to calculate validTo timestamp with the following script, I get the wrong timestamp:

```
"validTo": {
     "script": {
       "lang": "painless",
       "source": "doc[\u0027validTo\u0027].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli()"
     }
  }
```

The above script returns 1546439563000, which is Wednesday, January 2, 2019 2:32:43 PM

Does anyone know how what is wrong in the above calculation and how to get the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993167/elasticsearch-sort-by-dates-is-incorrect), `DD` should be `dd`:

```
 "validTo" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                            ^^
                            ||
                        change that
      }
```

`DD` is the day count for the year, i.e 02 = January 2nd